# 2 dl-hack3-cond-1 suppressed errors shown from valgrind -v

Tags: c, valgrind

I am getting two suppressed dl-hack3-cond-1 errors from valgrind when running valgrind -v. I use calloc in my code but I have made sure to free everything and set to NULL. Also made sure to typecast every calloc return. I have tried to do some research to see the meaning behind the error and found that it is related to dynamic linking but there was limited information about that as well. This is for a class and the instructor said that we cannot have any suppressed errors in our valgrind runs.

I have heard that this can happen from running on a 64 bit system, is there any truth to this? Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the 64-bit system. Finally got Valgrind to install on my laptop and the same thing runs with 0 errors. Thank you for the time and thought though.

Answer (score 3):

If your instructor has really said that then they are a fool...

The default suppressions shipped with `valgrind` are there for a reason, because there are some errors in standard system libraries that you are not going to be able to get rid of no matter what you do in your own code.

In many cases they may be false positives but in any case the valgrind developers have decided that they are not something that users can or should be trying to do anything about which is why they have supplied suppressions for them as part of the default installation.

Maybe your instructor really meant that you shouldn't have any suppressed errors in your own code? That would be an entirely reasonable requirement.

Comment: I don't know what the difference is? How can you tell whether the error is with the library or in my code?

Comment: Well if it's one of the builtin ones (and that is) then it will be in a system library. That suppression only catches things in a library whose name matches `*/lib*/ld-2.16*.so*` which is to say in the dynamic linker which is part of glibc.